# How does Retrofit.create() extenstion function works with no class refrence parameter?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, dagger-hilt, kotlin-extension

I have a `Hilt` module to provide `Retrofit` API in my app like so:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkDataModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(
                HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                    level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                }
            )
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMyApi(client: OkHttpClient): MyApi {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MyApi.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
            .create()
    }
}
```

And it is my API `interface`:

```
interface MyApi {

    @GET("search")
    suspend fun search(): searchDto

    companion object {
        const val BASE_URL = "https://myapi.com/"
    }
}
```

The question is how the Retrofits `create()` extension function knows which class should it return despite I did not pass any information about the `MyApi` interface to it. The create function implementation is this:

```
inline fun <reified T> Retrofit.create(): T = create(T::class.java)
```

How does `create(T::class.java)` return `MyApi` in spite of I did not provide any type for `T`?

My retrofit version is `2.9.0`

Comment: In `fun provideMyApi(client: OkHttpClient): MyApi` you defined MyApi as return type. That's how the T is statically typed.

Comment: @Thommy How does this type infer happen based on return type?